# Remove Link from author and date meta on Homepage of WordPress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

On my blog homepage, Author and date meta (Author name and date) are in link form. I want to show them only in text. When I tried to remove the link the text is also removed. Kindly help me to remove the link. Codes of display.php are

```
if (!function_exists('swift_meta_generator')):
/**
 * Generate post meta.
 *
 * Prints the post meta information based on the options set in theme options page.
 * Called around post titles on home page and single pages.
 *
 * @param    array $meta post meta order set in options page.
 * @param    string $classes html classes for the post meta wrapper.
 *
 */
function swift_meta_generator($meta, $classes)
{
    $data = '<div class="entry-meta ' . $classes . '">';
    $size = count($meta);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        switch ($meta[$i]) {
            case 'text' :
                if ((current_time('timestamp', 1) - get_the_date('U')) < 86400)
                    $meta[$i + 1] = preg_replace('(on)', '', $meta[$i + 1]);
                $data .= $meta[$i + 1];
                $i++;
                break;

            case 'author' :
                $data .= '<span class="vcard author fa-user"><a class="" href="' . esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))) . '" rel="author"><span class="fn">' . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . '</span></a></span> ';
                break;

            case 'author_avatar' :
                $data .= get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 16 );
                $data .= '&nbsp;<span class="vcard author"><a class="" href="' . esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))) . '" rel="author"><span class="fn">' . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . '</span></a></span> ';

                break;

            case 'date' :
                if ((current_time('timestamp', 1) - get_the_date('U')) < 86400)
                    $date = human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' '.__('ago','swift');
                else
                    $date = get_the_date();

                $data .= '<span class="date updated fa-clock-o"><a class="" href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" title="' . esc_attr(get_the_time()) . '" rel="bookmark">';
                $data .= '<time class="entry-date" datetime="' . esc_attr(get_the_date('c')) . '">' . esc_html($date) . '</time></a></span> ';
                break;

            case 'updated_on' :
                if ((current_time('timestamp', 1) - get_the_modified_date('U')) < 86400)
                    $date = human_time_diff(get_post_modified_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' '.__('ago','swift');
                else
                    $date = get_the_modified_date();

                $data .= '<span class="date updated fa-clock-o"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" title="' . esc_attr(get_post_modified_time()) . '" rel="bookmark">';
                $data .= '<time class="entry-date" datetime="' . esc_attr(get_the_modified_date('c')) . '">' . esc_html($date) . '</time></a></span> ';
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace this code with your code

```
if (!function_exists('swift_meta_generator')):
/**
* Generate post meta.
*
* Prints the post meta information based on the options set in theme options page.
* Called around post titles on home page and single pages.
*
* @param    array $meta post meta order set in options page.
* @param    string $classes html classes for the post meta wrapper.
*
*/
function swift_meta_generator($meta, $classes)
{
$data = '<div class="entry-meta ' . $classes . '">';
$size = count($meta);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
switch ($meta[$i]) {
    case 'text' :
        if ((current_time('timestamp', 1) - get_the_date('U')) < 86400)
            $meta[$i + 1] = preg_replace('(on)', '', $meta[$i + 1]);
        $data .= $meta[$i + 1];
        $i++;
        break;

    case 'author' :
        $data .= '<span class="vcard author fa-user"><span class="fn">' . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . '</span></span> ';
        break;

    case 'author_avatar' :
        $data .= get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 16 );
        $data .= '&nbsp;<span class="vcard author"><a class="" href="' . esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))) . '" rel="author"><span class="fn">' . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . '</span></a></span> ';

        break;

    case 'date' :
        if ((current_time('timestamp', 1) - get_the_date('U')) < 86400)
            $date = human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' '.__('ago','swift');
        else
            $date = get_the_date();

        $data .= '<span class="date updated fa-clock-o">' . esc_attr(get_the_time()) . '</span>';
        $data .= '<time class="entry-date" datetime="' . esc_attr(get_the_date('c')) . '">' . esc_html($date) . '</time></span> ';
        break;

    case 'updated_on' :
        if ((current_time('timestamp', 1) - get_the_modified_date('U')) < 86400)
            $date = human_time_diff(get_post_modified_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' '.__('ago','swift');
        else
            $date = get_the_modified_date();

        $data .= '<span class="date updated fa-clock-o"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" title="' . esc_attr(get_post_modified_time()) . '" rel="bookmark">';
        $data .= '<time class="entry-date" datetime="' . esc_attr(get_the_modified_date('c')) . '">' . esc_html($date) . '</time></a></span> ';
```

This code removed links from your author and date .... Hope that works fine to you.

Comment: Thank you so much Laraib, God bless you. I was striving for a long time. You have done this for me. great.